# European COST Actions

Tags: funding, europe

I would like to ask if you think  the European COST Actions are interesting for researchers? Do you see any potential advantage to join any of them? If yes, I would like to ask you how I could join one action of my interest, they do not explain properly in the website.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to become [an external expert](http://www.cost.eu/participate/external_experts). Otherwise, you'll have to involve your institution.

Answer (score 2):

You can get involved in a COST Action through various means and steps, as explained in http://www.cost.eu/participate

In short, you can join as a member of a workgroup of the Action (wide open), as a management committee member (or substitute) - nominated by your country for an already accepted Action, as a proposal submitter - almost automatic nomination, as a (usually Ph.D. student) researcher participating in short-term scientific missions (STSM), etc.

If it is interesting? I think yes and that's why they are there (and receiving funding) for some 40 years now.

IMHO: Being involved as an external expert (e.g., to evaluate proposals) is the hardest path as your role assumes that you understand how the whole thing works so as to provide a fair evaluation. While there are guidelines in place to help you with this, having first-hand experience by being involved in some Actions is much more useful.